# Lightswitch Desktop Application Wont Install in XP SP3

Tags: windows-xp, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a desktop application developed with Lightswitch using Visual Studio 2012.

The app installs perfectly on a Windows 7 machine but when I try to install it on an XP SP3 machine I get:

> setup.exe is not a valid Win32-Application

I've tried using:

> editbin setup.exe /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS,5.01 /OSVERSION:5.1

but then I get the following error:

> the procedure entry point InitializeCriticalSectionEX could not be
>   located in the dynamic link library Kernal32.dll

I've spent ages getting this rapid development application to do exactly what I want it to do and to be scuppered at the last hurdle really bites. So if anyone can help me to get this thing to work on an XP machine I'd be really, really grateful.

Comment: "I've spent ages getting this rapid development application to do exactly what I want it to do" this is an oxymoron!

Comment: Exactly!! I'm glad the point wasn't missed!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I was caught out with the 'can't compile an application in VS2012 for XP' issue. So I'm gonna redevelop the app in VS2010. Nice one Microsoft...

[Setup.exe is not a valid Win32 application](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsnetsetup/archive/2012/10/16/setup-exe-is-not-a-valid-win32-application.aspx)