# Lightswitch Desktop Application Wont Run in XP SP3

Tags: deployment, windows-xp-sp3, lightswitch-2012

I have developed an application in Lightswitch 2012, and now need to deploy it to a desktop PC running XP SP3.

I have already looked at two previous posts [Can't run Lightswitch 2012 Programm under Windows XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12140643/cant-run-lightswitch-2012-programm-under-windows-xp) and 
[Lightswitch Desktop Application Wont Install in XP SP3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838006/lightswitch-desktop-application-wont-install-in-xp-sp3)

The two posts both refer to executing [`editbin vslshost.exe /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS,5.01 /OSVERSION:5.1`] to modify the vslshost.exe file, though only the first post says it worked.

In my case, I have tried the above to update the vslshost.exe file, but when I publish my LS2012 project it reverts back to the default vslshost.exe file. And if I manually swap the file with the copy I modified, when I run the deployed app I get the following error:

```
System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (HashValidation)
    - File, vslshost.exe, has a different computed hash than specified in manifest.
    - Source: System.Deployment
```

So, the questions are

1. am I doing something wrong?
2. is there a master copy of vslshost.exe I need to update instead?

(BTW, I also ran the VS2012 (KB270250 from VS2012 Update 1 CTP 4))

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

As this is an internal company app, I have just convinced our IT guy to upgrade the machine, because the certain grief of trying the different possible solutions was just too much.

BUT if you MUST deploy to XP

To find out more, here are two pretty exhaustive posts with input directly from the Lightswitch team:

[Progress on LS2012 desktop apps installing AND running on XP yet?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitch/thread/e00e343a-552d-4a6f-8204-0e0f02fde09a/)

[Windows XP 32 bit deployment](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitch/thread/19e5dd5e-4d47-48c1-bc6f-b978f31d2471)

Enjoy....(???)